# After insert trigger is blocking the whole table and process

Tags: sql-server, loops, block

I am trying to execute a program when other program inserts a value into a table. I have applied the After trigger on the table let's say "table1" when program A inserts value into table1 it must execute the program B which takes the input from the same table1.

```
USE [capstone]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
CREATE trigger [dbo].[api_trig] on [dbo].[search]
after insert
AS
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'c:\Python34\python.exe c:\Python34\search_test.py'
```

this search_test program takes input from the same table i.e; search. But once we insert or perform any operation on that table will be executing for ages as it is into some kind of loop and gives timed out error.

TO stop this and to access the table again i have to kill the process by this method
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/77fc7e09-ed14-481f-89d5-d5e143dab7bd/trying-to-delete-a-table-in-sql-server-management-studio-and-getting-a-strange-error?forum=sqldatabaseengine
 and error shows me that the program search_test is blocking the process of query execution.
Please help me with this I am exhausted finding the reason/solution of the error
TIA

Comment: What is the purpose of this design ?  In general, you don't want to call external (or any) programs from a trigger.  If the whole point is to have program B run with the new records, then read up on Service-Brokers, or add a timestamp or identity column and write a scheduled task that takes all of the new data and runs the process on them.  This way you "physically" detach the execution from the insert itself, but still have the two commands coupled together "logically".

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation says xp_cmdshell waits for the command to complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx), meaning the process which caused the trigger will not have the opportunity to release and locks or commit any transactions until after your program runs.

A quick hack would be to have xp_cmdshell run a program which then launches your target program as a separate process then exits. That would allow xp_cmdshell to return, the trigger to complete, and the caller to release locks/commit transactions.

The problem with that though is your second program may see stale/missing data if the trigger is run in a transaction.  Your program may try and access the data before the transaction has been successfully committed, or the parent may have rolled back the transaction.

You should re-design your logic so the program doing the inserting also launches the second program after it completes the insert transaction successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, can you please tell me how to execute the operating system commands from the visual studio 2012. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Calling an external program from inside a trigger is really bad idea.

The behavior you observe is just one of many potential pitfalls.

I strongly recommend you reconsider the design, and perform only the necessary operations in the AFTER INSERT trigger, and use a different mechanism for triggering the external process.

As a rudimentary example, have the AFTER INSERT trigger insert a row to a queue table. And have a separate external daemon polling the queue table for new rows.